# my OpenGL application works on ATI, but doesn't work o nNVIDIA pc's

Tags: c++, opengl

I am working on a game engine, with C++ and OpenGL, as a learning project. When I am at my home PC, which has an ATI graphics card, everything is ok. Up to now, all the engine can do is to display a sprite, and it does it with no problem. At work, there are two Windows PC's with NVIDIA cards, and when I run the program, it acts as if OpenGL is not here.

I checked for `glGetIntegerv(GL_MAJOR_VERSION); glGetIntegerv(GL_MINOR_VERSION);` and it yielded 4.5

Here is my init function:

```
    namespace windows
    {
        HGLRC OpenGLWindows::hglrc;

        bool OpenGLWindows::initialize(HWND& hwnd, HDC& hdc)
        {   
            PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;

            const int pixelFormatAttribList[] =
            {
                WGL_DRAW_TO_WINDOW_ARB, GL_TRUE,
                WGL_SUPPORT_OPENGL_ARB, GL_TRUE,
                WGL_DOUBLE_BUFFER_ARB, GL_TRUE,
                WGL_PIXEL_TYPE_ARB, WGL_TYPE_RGBA_ARB,
                WGL_COLOR_BITS_ARB, 32,
                WGL_DEPTH_BITS_ARB, 24,
                WGL_STENCIL_BITS_ARB, 8,
                0,        //End
            };



            //choose pixel format
            int     pixelFormat;
            UINT    numFormats;

            //dummy context
            hglrc = wglCreateContext(hdc);
            wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hglrc);

            //initialize glew
            glewExperimental = TRUE;
            GLenum err = glewInit();
            std::cout << glewGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;
            if (err != GLEW_OK)
            {
                std::cout << "Error: GLEW couldn't be initialized = " << glewGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;
                return false;
            }


            assert(hwnd != NULL);

            //set pixel format

            if (!WGL_ARB_pixel_format) errorQuit("WGL_ARB_pixel_format not supported");
            wglChoosePixelFormatARB = (PFNWGLCHOOSEPIXELFORMATARBPROC)wglGetProcAddress("wglChoosePixelFormatARB");
            if (!wglChoosePixelFormatARB(hdc, pixelFormatAttribList, NULL, 1, &pixelFormat, &numFormats))
            {
                std::cout << "Error: pixel format could not be created" << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                SetPixelFormat(hdc, pixelFormat, &pfd);
            }

            //create real context
            int contextAttribList[5] =
            {
                WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
                WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 0, 0
            };
            if (!WGL_ARB_create_context) errorQuit("WGL_ARB_create_context not supported");
            wglCreateContextAttribsARB = (PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC)wglGetProcAddress("wglCreateContextAttribsARB");
            hglrc = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(hdc, 0, contextAttribList);

            if (!wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hglrc))
            {
                errorQuit("OpenGL context creation failed");
            }

            GLint major;
            GLint minor;
            glGetIntegerv(GL_MAJOR_VERSION, &major);
            glGetIntegerv(GL_MINOR_VERSION, &minor);
            std::cout << "GL version = " << major << "." << minor << std::endl;

            std::cout << glGetString(GL_VENDOR) << std::endl;
            std::cout << glGetString(GL_RENDERER) << std::endl;

            glEnable(GL_BLEND);
            glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

            return true;
        }

        void    OpenGLWindows::shutDown(HWND& hwnd, HDC& hdc)
        {
            wglMakeCurrent(hdc, NULL);
            wglDeleteContext(hglrc);
        }
    }
```

I am looking at forums for hours, and topics that I found close to this one always got crashes, and their solutions didn't work. I don't get any crashes, just a window, with the color I specified while creating the window context. I wonder what I am doing wrong.

EDIT: I just created a whole dummy window, and now it works with NVIDIA too.

Comment: I didn't look your code in depth, but this kind of problem is usually caused by code relying on non-standard behavior. If you haven't done it already, check the documentation of the functions you're using and see if you're using them properly (e.g. passing the right parameters).

Comment: I checked, everything looks ok, unless I misunderstood what you meant by "right parameters". When I checked at home,  `glGetIntegerv(GL_MAJOR_VERSION, &major);            glGetIntegerv(GL_MINOR_VERSION, &minor);`
 yielded 3.0. Could it be a version issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the `WGL_ARB_pixel_format` extension, and are running into some chicken-and-egg problem: To get the extension function pointers, you create a GL context first. But, to create a GL context, *you need to set a pixel format for your window first*: The [reference page for `wglCreateContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374379%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) explicitely states:

> A rendering context is not the same as a device context. **Set the pixel format of the device context before creating a rendering context.**

So you must use the standard [`ChoosePixelFormat()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) & [`SetPixelFormat()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd369049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) approach to reliably create your helper context to query the WGL extensions.

However, `SetPixelFormat` must not be used more than once on the same window:

> Setting the pixel format of a window more than once can lead to significant complications for the Window Manager and for multithread applications, so it is not allowed. **An application can only set the pixel format of a window one time. Once a window's pixel format is set, it cannot be changed.**

This means that when the second pixel format for your "real" context differs from the pixel format for the dummy, your approach will fail. This is the reason why one typically uses a separate window for the dummy context (which is possibly never mapped to the screen), and immediately destroys it again.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Just that I am curious, is there a reason why my code worked with ATI and not NVIDIA?

Comment: I've no idea what happens when you create a GL context without setting a PixelFormat first. It might have worked by accident only.